# Make classes accessible only by static object

Tags: c#, .net, static-classes

I'm creating a library in .Net

I have a static class called DataManager.

```
public static class NewDataManager
{
    public static Soccer Soccer { get; private set; }

    static NewDataManager()
    {
         Soccer =  new Classes.Soccer.Soccer();
    }
}
```

Soccer class is like:

```
public class Soccer
{
    public static Mapping.Mapping Mappings { get; private set; }

    public Soccer()
    {
        Mappings = new Mapping.Mapping();
    }
}
```

And Mapping class is just an another public empty class.

When i use this project as a reference in another project, i can access my objects like

```
NewDataManager.Soccer.Mappings
```

That's fine, this is what i want. The problem is, i can initialize all classes in referencing project like

```
var s = new Soccer();
var m = new Mapping();
```

I want those classes accessible only via my `NewDataManager` class, projects using my library should not be able to initialize classes.

How can i restrict that?

Comment: all other classes that newdatamanager - set them to Internal/private  instead of public

Comment: Is there a reason that `Soccer` isn't static itself? Or `Mappings` for that matter?

Comment: @VisualBean internal/private won't make it accessible in his project at all - even if he wanted to access it via `NewDataManager`

Comment: @MattBurland There is no any reason for that. I just created them like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent another assembly from instantiating a class, make its constructor `internal`:

```
public class Soccer
{
    public static Mapping.Mapping Mappings { get; private set; }

    internal Soccer()  //  <-- instead of 'public'
    {
        Mappings = new Mapping.Mapping();
    }
}

public class Mapping
{
    internal Mapping()
    {
    }
}
```

(By the way, it looks like you have namespaces named `Soccer` and `Mapping`. [Don't do this.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to effectively achieve what you want. Nest `Soccer` inside `NewDataManager` and then you can do something like this:

```
public static class NewDataManager
{
    public static ISoccer SoccerInstance { get; private set; }

    static NewDataManager()
    {
         SoccerInstance =  new Soccer();
    }

    private class Soccer : ISoccer
    {

        public Soccer()
        {
        }
    }
}

public interface ISoccer {}
```

Making the nested class `private` means it can't be accessed outside of `NewDataManger`, but you can still expose it by having it implement a public interface. You can, of course, add whatever properties you need exposed to the interface so that they will be available to the calling code. I simplfied my example by leaving out the `Mapping` property.

Now if you don't want to nest classes, you don't have to. You can mark them `internal` and they won't be visible to other assemblies, but they will be visible inside the same assembly. That means classes in the same assembly other than `NewDataManger` will be  able to see them (and create new instances), but other assemblies won't. Which might be enough for you.

Comment: Nested classes... Great solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the classes are public - you can access them from "anywhere"

public

```
The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.
```

private

```
The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.
```

protected

```
The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.
```

internal

```
The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.
```

[MSDN article about access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Comment: This explains the problem, but doesn't really answer the question of how to achieve what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Updated answer -> in progress of testing

Comment: You can't make the class `internal` and then expose it as a `public` property.

Answer (score 0):

Let me extend VisualBean's solution:
Classes have their accessability trait, just like functions, as he described - public, private, protected, internal, etc.

So the first solution is just defining the NewDataManager and Soccer classes in the same assembly, and making Soccer internal and NewDataManager public, like so:

```
public class NewDataManager{/*Your code goes here*/}
internal class Soccer{/*Your code goes here, 2*/}
```

and in another file, you can put the rest of the code.

However though, There are alternatives which might be more fit (depending on your situation). If a class should only be accessible to a single type of another class, imho it should be related to that class. In order to include classes within classes, you have 2 approaches:

Either making the constructor protected, and making the class inherit the other class (which is a good solution if the objects extend each other),
i.e

```
class Soccer{protected Soccer(){} /*Rest of the code goes here*/}
class NewDataManager:Soccer{// NewDataManagerStuff }
```

Or making the generation an event which would require the sender to be the class you are looking for, which might be slightly more complicated.

Good luck, I hope helped you. :)

Comment: NewDataManager will have more classes like Soccer, so i can't derive it from Soccer.

Answer (score -1):

Just insert the `Mapping` class into `NewDataManager` like this:

```
public static partial class NewDataManager 
{
    // NewDataManager class code
}

public partial class NewDataManager
{
    public static class Mapping
    {
        // Mapping class code
    }
}
```

OR

```
public static class NewDataManager 
{
    // NewDataManager class code

    public static class Mapping
    {
        //Mapping class code
    }
}
```